# comparison difference object in one arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections, compare

need help.Have create arraylist and then add multiple object(in my case,add 2 type object inside arraylist).Then sort each object inside arraylist .Able to sort but I think my coding is too long.Is their any way or method to make it simple and effective.Hope you guys can help.That all,hope you can help.Thank you.

```
public class Sample {


    static ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){


        //initialize object
        User user1 = new User("user1","1");
        User user2 = new User("user1","3");
        Staff staf1 = new Staff("staf1","2");
        Staff staf2 = new Staff("staf2","4");

        //add object to arraylist
        object.add(user1);
        object.add(user2);
        object.add(staf1);
        object.add(staf2);


        //sort
        Collections.sort(object,new Comparator<Object>() {
            Object one,two;

            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                User user1,user2;
                Staff staf1,staf2;

                ///identify ol class
                if(o1 instanceof User){
                   user1 = (User) o1;
                   one = (Object) user1;
                }else if(o1 instanceof Staff){
                    staf1 = (Staff) o1;
                    one = (Object) staf1;
                }

                //identify o2 class
                if(o2 instanceof User){
                     user2 = (User) o2;
                     two = (Object) user2;

                }else if(o2 instanceof Staff){
                    staf2 = (Staff) o2;
                    two = (Object) staf2;
                }

                //identify each object class
                //then compare value
                if(one instanceof User && two instanceof User){
                    //execute process
                    User userOne = (User) one;
                    User userTwo = (User) two;
                    return userOne.getRegister().compareTo(userTwo.getRegister());

                }else if(one instanceof Staff && two instanceof Staff){
                     //execute process
                    Staff stafOne = (Staff) one;
                    Staff stafTwo = (Staff) two;
                    return stafOne.getRegister().compareTo(stafTwo.getRegister());

                }else if(one instanceof User && two instanceof Staff){
                     //execute process 
                    User userOne = (User) one;
                    Staff stafTwo = (Staff) two;
                     return userOne.getRegister().compareTo(stafTwo.getRegister());
                }else if(one instanceof Staff && two instanceof User){
                     //execute process
                    Staff stafOne = (Staff) one;
                    User userTwo = (User) two;
                    return  stafOne.getRegister().compareTo(userTwo.getRegister());
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        });

        //display item
        for(Object object : object){   
           if(object instanceof User){
               User user = (User)object;
               //display data
               System.out.println(user.getRegister());
           }else if(object instanceof Staff){
               Staff staf = (Staff) object;
               //display data
               System.out.println(staf.getRegister());
           }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use inheritance? It seems that they are using same field and methods

Comment: i can use inheritance.but right now i want to learn  adding object(difference type) inside arraylist and sort it and that why i created same field and method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your objects have the same fields and methods I am recomend you to use `inheritance` int this situation. First you have to exclude one abstract class which be a parent of yours two classes:

```
public abstract class Parent implements Comparable<Parent> { 

    abstract Integer getRegister();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Parent parent) {
        return this.getRegister().compareTo(parent.getRegister());
    }

}
```

Then you have to make, that your classes `User` and `Staff` will extends `Person` class. Then, you can create list: `List<Parent> list` and sort it by its own comparator. So assuming there are matchinbg constructors available, `User extends Parent` and `Staff extends Parent`:

```
final List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new User("user1","1"));
list.add(new User("user1","3"));
list.add(new Staff("staf1","2"));
list.add(new Staff("staf2","4"));
Collections.sort(list);
```

**EDIT (as OP don't want to use inheritance):**

Instead of checking few times, do it only once and get register field in moment you know about type.

```
@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    Integer register1 = null;
    Integer register2 = null;

    if(o1 instanceof User) {
        register1 = ((User)o1).getRegister();
    } else if(o1 instanceof Staff) {
        register1 = ((Staff)o1).getRegister();
    }

    if(o2 instanceof User) {
        register2 = ((User)o2).getRegister();
    } else if(o1 instanceof Staff) {
        register2 = ((Staff)o2).getRegister();
    }

    if(register1 != null && register2 != null) {
        return register1.compareTo(register2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer,but right now i want to learn  adding object(difference type) inside arraylist and sort it and that why i created same field and method.

Comment: It is not a good practice to adding different objects (which are not connected by parent class) to not specified list. It is because you have to use `instanceof` and casting and all stuff you want to avoid in programming.

Comment: And, of course, you question was how `to make it simple and effective` and inheritance is the `simple and effective` way